# Django : initialize database without migrations

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

Sorry, I'm pretty novice on Django. I have some little notice already, but completly lack of experience.
So the questions sound silly, but I could not find it exactly in this general form.
So...
Let's say, I have some Django project already done by someone. Now I have two situations :

1. I have the latest version of project code. But I have nothing about database : neither database, nor migrations.
   To give some example, the code was on some Git, but the database and migrations files were on some server and this server is lost.

I'd like to understand if I could still initialize the project from zero ?

Get the new server with empty database. I clone git code of project. Launch

```
manage.py makemigrations
manage.py migrate
```

and I'll get new database initialized by our models files ?

Is it correct ?
Are there some pitfalls about it ?

2. the second situation is similar, but not exactly.

Now I have some database-dump and also some migrations. But probably not all them.

So I do not know how much my code is different from dump and migrations.
I saw already the questions about similar situations. It seems that globally the solution is something like this :

- clone the code; copy (or not?) existent migrations
- create new database and load dump
- run

```
manage.py makemigrations
manage.py migrate --fake

manage.py makemigrations
manage.py migrate
```

May be I need to modify (remove) some migrations-files before "fake" run or do some other trics... But globally this is the approach.

Is it correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Django version is important to this question. It is not stated so - for this answer - it's assumed to be at least 1.7 or higher up to current.

Upfront: learn from this and start committing the migration files as part of the code to avoid this situation. Even though these files are most of the time auto-generated, they should be part of the code base.

### 1. Initialize from scratch without migration files

You are correct in your assumption. Here are more details:

1. Create the database. The database name should be stated in the settings.py (or settings/base.py or similar) file. For postgres, you could run `$ createdb name_of_db` from the shell.
2. run `./manage.py makemigrations`. This should create `migrations` directories and files in all of your apps. If there are no new files, run the command with explicitly stating the apps like `./manage.py makemigrations my_app`. See the help of this command on how to specify apps.
3. run `./manage.py migrate`. This should create all the necessary tables and constraints in the database you created in step 1.

### 2. Get a dump to work without migrations files

There are two situtations and in depends in which one you are in.

#### 2.1 The dump is most current, as is the code

This means that the version of the database is aligned with the version of your code and you are just missing the migration files.

In this case:

1. Start of with an empty database and follow the steps above (section 1).
2. Then load the dump into the database.
3. optionally: you can have a look into the table `django_migrations` in the database and empty it, if you want.
4. run `./manage.py migrate --fake`

#### 2.2 The dump is not aligned with the codebase

You can try the steps in 2.1. The system might tell you via warnings and errors where the database and the migrations divert. You could try to change the dump until everything runs.

You can also use the [inspectdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb) to check the difference between the tables and the models.

Alternatively you can try the following:

1. Load the dump into the database used by django
2. dump the data into fixtures using the [dumpdata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata) command.
3. drop and recreate the database so that it is empty.
4. create fresh migrations and run them (see section 1 above)
5. load the fixtures with [loaddata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#loaddata) command

This way you can be sure that the database (especially constraints) is aligned with the Django code.

Comment: Thank you very much for very complete response. Very appreciate different use-cases scenarios.

Comment: About version. I didn't precise it, because my question was more general. It has some link to a real project I worked on, but the situation of real-project is more complicated.
So I asked general question to be sure that I understand correctly the basics of Django.

Nevertheless the real project is on Django 2.2 so I could use your advice. :-)